How does a plugin work?
Why does a node get created in ROS2 when I use this plugin(libgazebo_ros_diff_drive)?
Can a plugin really create a node for ROS?
How exactly does a plugin connect to ROS topics, read the data, and send it?
CODE:

  <ros>
    <!-- <namespace>/tb3</namespace> -->
  </ros>

  <update_rate>30</update_rate>

  <!-- wheels -->
  <left_joint>left_wheel_hinge</left_joint>
  <right_joint>right_wheel_hinge</right_joint>

  <!-- kinematics -->
  <wheel_separation>0.287</wheel_separation>
  <wheel_diameter>0.066</wheel_diameter>

  <!-- limits -->
  <max_wheel_torque>20</max_wheel_torque>
  <max_wheel_acceleration>1.0</max_wheel_acceleration>

  <command_topic>cmd_vel</command_topic>

  <!-- output -->
  <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
  <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
  <publish_wheel_tf>false</publish_wheel_tf>

  <odometry_topic>odom</odometry_topic>
  <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
  <robot_base_frame>chassis</robot_base_frame>

</plugin>


Welcome to Robotics Alireza, but I'm afraid that questions which are as broad as this are off-topic because answers would need to be too long. As it says in [ask] If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. We prefer practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face, so please take a look at [ask], [about] and the Robotics question checklist for advice on writing a good question.
